# Why Intellisense doesn't work in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-management-studio

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.

I have tried these:

1. Tools->Options->Query Execution->SQL Server->General, make sure “By default, open new queries in SQLCMD mode” is unchecked
2. Go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> General >> IntelliSense
   Select Auto List Members and Check Parameter Information.
3. Restarted, repaired Visual Studio 2010
4. Installed VS 2010 SP1
5. Query/Intellisense Enabled selected

But still it doesn't work.

Any clue?

Comment: Are you connecting to a SQL Server 2008+ DB when trying to use Intellisense? Even with the new SSMS, Intellisense won't work for DBs in prior versions.

Comment: What does Visual Studio 2010 have to do with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Is it completely disabled or is it just not recognizing your stuff? Generally, you'll need to refresh (_shift+ctrl+r_) or restart SMSS for intellisense to pick up new objects.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: I believe it's even enough if the database compatibility level is set to 2005 (90) or prior.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 apparantly broke something:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/650569/ssms-2008-r2-is-losing-intellisense-after-installing-visual-studio-2010-sp1

Do you have Service Pack 1 for SQL Server installed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you install VS2010 SP1 it breaks intelliSense of SQL Server 2008 R2. You will need to install either CU or SP1 for SQL Server 2008 R2 mentioned in this [Support KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482) from MSFT.